Kernel Panic when trying to write in Flash after kernel update
I recently updated my Linux Kernel from 5.4.104 to 5.15 and after that i cant write anymore on my QSPI NOR FLASH. I did a little research and it seems that the cadence qspi controller started using the spi-mem framework and i suspect that this screwed my QSPI write operations. during kernel bringup it seems that everything is just fine, as it can be seen below:
[    1.400740] spi-nor spi0.0: found n25q128a13, expected n25q512a
[    1.406841] spi-nor spi0.0: n25q128a13 (16384 Kbytes)
[    1.411954] 8 fixed-partitions partitions found on MTD device ff705000.flash.0
[    1.419165] Creating 8 MTD partitions on "ff705000.flash.0":
[    1.424806] 0x000000000000-0x000000001000 : "SPL/u-boot image"
[    1.431977] 0x000000001000-0x000000002000 : "SPL/u-boot dtb"
[    1.438908] 0x000000002000-0x000000003000 : "reserved-0"
[    1.445441] 0x000000003000-0x000000004000 : "reserved-1"
[    1.452053] 0x000000200000-0x000000201000 : "u-boot environment 1"
[    1.459482] 0x000000210000-0x000000211000 : "u-boot environment 2"
[    1.466895] 0x000000800000-0x000000c00000 : "FPGA safe image"
[    1.473928] 0x000000c00000-0x000001000000 : "FPGA user image"

reading seems fine but when i try to read i gives me a kernel panic:
# echo "hello" > /dev/mtdblock7
[ 1146.935881] 8<--- cut here ---
[ 1146.938943] Unhandled fault: imprecise external abort (0x1406) at 0x00504e1c
[ 1146.945966] pgd = 1a543702
[ 1146.948667] [00504e1c] *pgd=380dc831
[ 1146.952240] Internal error: : 1406 [#1] SMP ARM
[ 1146.956756] Modules linked in:
[ 1146.959803] CPU: 1 PID: 613 Comm: sh Not tainted 5.15.0-142467-gad617140bb24-dirty #18
[ 1146.967692] Hardware name: Altera SOCFPGA
[ 1146.971688] PC is at cqspi_exec_mem_op+0xab8/0xfec
[ 1146.976485] LR is at arm_heavy_mb+0x2c/0x48
[ 1146.980660] pc : [<c06b3b80>]    lr : [<c0117b70>]    psr: 20030013
[ 1146.986902] sp : c23899b8  ip : c23899a8  fp : c2389a14
[ 1146.992106] r10: 00000100  r9 : f08e4000  r8 : c1234040
[ 1146.997310] r7 : c1213b80  r6 : c1213b80  r5 : 00000000  r4 : c2389c18
[ 1147.003810] r3 : 00000001  r2 : 00000730  r1 : 00000000  r0 : 00000000
[ 1147.010308] Flags: nzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment none
[ 1147.017419] Control: 10c5387d  Table: 02a1404a  DAC: 00000051
[ 1147.023141] Register r0 information: NULL pointer
[ 1147.027831] Register r1 information: NULL pointer
[ 1147.032518] Register r2 information: non-paged memory
[ 1147.037551] Register r3 information: non-paged memory
[ 1147.042584] Register r4 information: non-slab/vmalloc memory
[ 1147.048223] Register r5 information: NULL pointer
[ 1147.052910] Register r6 information: slab kmalloc-2k start c1213800 pointer offset 896 size 2048
[ 1147.061678] Register r7 information: slab kmalloc-2k start c1213800 pointer offset 896 size 2048
[ 1147.070443] Register r8 information: slab kmalloc-8k start c1234000 pointer offset 64 size 8192
[ 1147.079122] Register r9 information: 0-page vmalloc region starting at 0xf08e4000 allocated at __devm_ioremap_resource+0x170/0x1e8
[ 1147.090823] Register r10 information: non-paged memory
[ 1147.095944] Register r11 information: non-slab/vmalloc memory
[ 1147.101669] Register r12 information: non-slab/vmalloc memory
[ 1147.107395] Process sh (pid: 613, stack limit = 0x4e67e691)
[ 1147.112949] Stack: (0xc23899b8 to 0xc238a000)
[ 1147.117293] 99a0:                                                       c01a5f98 c076e370
.
.
.

Has anyone encountered this kind of problem and knows how to solve it? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.
